# javascript module not being found

Tags: javascript, html, sorttable.js

I have a bunch of web pages where I have an identical construct:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="sorttable.js"></script>
    <noscript>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="60">
    </noscript>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        var sURL = unescape(window.location.pathname);
        function doLoad()
        { 
            setTimeout( "parent.frames['header_frame'].document.submitform.submit()", 60*1000 ); 
        }
        function refresh()
        { 
            window.location.href = sURL; 
        }
        //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function refresh()
        { 
            window.location.replace( sURL ); 
        }
        //-->
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        <!--
        function refresh()
        { 
            window.location.reload( true ); 
        }
        //-->
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    .
    .
    .
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function() { sorttable.innerSortFunction.apply(document.getElementById("OpenFace-2"), []); doLoad(); }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

This works perfectly in every page except for one, where when the onload function runs it cannot find the sorttable code (which is loaded from sorttable.js up at the top). All these pages are part of the same application and are all in the same dir along with the js file. I do no get any errors in the apache log or the js console until that page loads, when I get:

```
sorttable.innerSortFunction is undefined
```

I can't see what makes this one page different. Can anyone see what is wrong here, or give me some pointers on how I can debug this further?

The code I pasted in is from the source of the page where it does not work, but it is identical as the pages where it does work.

Comment: Are you using [`http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/`](http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/)?

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout` nor `setInterval` with strings, because it's like evil `eval`! Use functions instead: `setTimeout(parent.frames['header_frame'].document.submitform.submit, 60e3)`

Comment: @Luxelin - yes, that's the sorttable we're using

Comment: are all pages   in the same path? there are any message in console browser? If this page is in other path, you need to fix <script src="sorttable.js"> to <script src="../sorttable.js"> for example

Comment: @Oriol - But that's not the problem - the doLoad() function works - it's the window.onload() that is throwing the error. But just to be sure I made the change you suggested - it did not fix my problem, and it caused my page to be refreshed continually, instead of just once per minute.

Comment: @Samuel - All the files are in the same directory and there are no messages until the page in question loads and I get the "sorttable.innerSortFunction is undefined" message

Comment: @LarryMartell No, that's not the problem. But please do it the good way :)

Comment: @ Oriol - like I said above, if I do it the way you suggest it caused my page to be refreshed continually, instead of just once per minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like on that page the table with id `OpenPhace-2` by which you try to sort have no needed class: `sortable`

The function `innerSortFunction` of `sorttable` object will be present only if there is any table with `sortable` class exists.

Comment: You mean ./ ? In any case I tried both / and ./, but neither one fixed the problem.

Comment: Can you please provide link to exact source code of library that you use?

Comment: Please check class name of the table on that page

Comment: The class name is correct. In fact the code I posted comes from a common function (this is PHP generated) that is used in all my pages and it works in every page but this one.

Comment: This indeed appears to be the issue. On that one page there is no table with the sortable class. Thanks much.